# importing csv to phpmyadmin with french accents

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a csv file with french accents. I am saving as csv from excel 2010. I don't see any options to choose encoding.

When I import with phpmyadmin I am getting the � instead of the accents.

I have tried choosing utf8 as well as latin1.

Comment: I have tried opening in notepad++ and changing the encoding to UTF-8 but still does not work.

Comment: I think clicking convert to utf-8 from notepadd++ works actually. I was just changing the encoding view.